# Use @ViewChildren/@ContentChildren in combination with router-outlet

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to build this :

```
┌--------------------------------------------┐
| -Page 1-   -Page 2-   -Page 3-             |
├----------┬---------------------------------┤
| Link 1   | <router-outlet></router-outlet> |
| Link 2   |                                 |
| Link 3   |                                 |
|          |                                 |
|          |                                 |
```

The list of links on the left depends on the page.

A typical page looks like this :

```html
<div>
  <app-component-1 appAnchor anchorTitle="Link 1"></app-component-1>
  <app-component-2 appAnchor anchorTitle="Link 2"></app-component-2>
  <app-component-3 appAnchor anchorTitle="Link 3"></app-component-3>
</div>
```

There are some directives `appAnchor` associated to `@Input() anchorTitle: string` . I want to automagically capture them and update the left menu.

The problem comes when I try to query those elements through the `router-outlet`.

So I tried :

```js
@ViewChildren(AnchorDirective)
viewChildren: QueryList<AnchorDirective>;

@ContentChildren(AnchorDirective)
contentChildren: QueryList<AnchorDirective>;

ngAfterContentInit(): void {
  console.log(`AppComponent[l.81] contentChildren`, this.contentChildren);
}

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  console.log(`AppComponent[l.85] viewChildren`, this.viewChildren);
}
```

but I always get some empty `QueryList` :

> QueryList {dirty: false, _results: Array(0), changes: EventEmitter, length: 0, last: undefined, …}

I also tried :

```js
@ContentChildren(AnchorDirective, {descendants: true})
@ContentChildren(AnchorDirective, {descendants: false})
```

Finally, I tried to query the elements at the last moment with :

```html
<router-outlet (activate)="foo()"></router-outlet>
```

Note : I don't want the children component to send data to the parent component via a service because it causes some `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` and [is considered as a bad practice](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4). I would really prefer to query the links directly from the parent component.

EDIT : Here is a [stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bcn1hd) showing the problem. If a `@ViewChildren` is used inside the component, everything works. But if the `@ViewChildren` is used from the root component, it fails.

Comment: @Drenai I am trying to reference elements which have the `AnchorDirective` (hence those that have the `appAnchor` attribute). I added a working StackBlitz at the end of the question.

Comment: Just wondering what is the end goal of all this? What do try to achieve? Because all this looks a little bit... weird and too complex.

Comment: @Dimanoid The aim is to do an automatic table of contents.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an on ongoing discussion [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14842) about how `ContentChildren` works, and it is closely related to your problem.

And in [this comment](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14842#issuecomment-470167258) it is explained that:

> In Angular content projection and queries it means "content as it was
>   written in a template" and not "content as visible in the DOM"

and

> The consequence of this mental model is that Angular only looks at the
>   nodes that are children in a template (and not children in the
>   rendered DOM).

Similar to the issue above, components activated via `router-outlet` are not considered as `ViewChildren` or `ContentChildren`. They are just DOM children, and that doesn't mean anything to angular in terms of View and Content queries. There is no way (as of today) that they an be queried with `ViewChild` or `ViewChildren` or `ContentChild` or `ContentChildren`

My suggestion to solve your issue is to use a combination of `activate` event and the `component` property of [RouterOutlet](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet#properties) to achieve the desired behavior. As such:

Define router-outlet as follows:

```html
<router-outlet #myRouterOutlet="outlet" (activate)='onActivate()'></router-outlet>
```

And use it as follows:

```js
@ViewChild("myRouterOutlet", { static: true }) routerOutlet: RouterOutlet;
nbViewChildren: number;
links = [];

onActivate(): void {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const ancList: QueryList<AnchorDirective> = (this.routerOutlet.component as any).children;

    this.nbViewChildren = ancList.length;
    this.links = ancList.map(anc => anc.anchorTitle);
  })
}
```

Here is a working demo with improved typing: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lopyp1

Also note that `setTimeout` is required because `onActivate` is fired during routing where the component life cycle hasn't started or finished yet. `setTimeout` ensures that the component lifecycle has completed, and that the component and underlying queries are ready as well.

Comment: i agree about tight coupling. but settimeout is harmless and it is preferred way of handling such cases. in a professional point of view i would also prefer using services for passing data between unrelated components. i provided this solution because in the question it is clearly stated that he didn't want to use services.

Comment: @Drenai I've been specifically using this type of approach to add ARIA tags, and certain css classes to my router outlet components - where I specifically don't want that component to know about it. For example `role='main'` might be added to component X but only if it's top level. Things like that. Was working great until Ivy reversed the order of newly inserted elements!

Answer (score 3):

The `(activate)="handleActivate($event)"` option won't work, as the `router-outlet` elements won't have been initialized yet. The `$event` in that case is indeed the component instance, but it's not really helpful here

The `ViewChildren`, `ContentChildren` don't seem to work for `router-outlet`. I didn't think they would, but tested it a good bit with your StackBlitz demo

You'll have to use a service, which is the standard way of doing it, and by far the most flexible. You will be able to get around the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` with ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges(), or better still, use a BehaviorSubject, and `next` the values from that. In your template subscribe using `async` pipe, and you won't get those errors